# PostgreSQL - CREATE INDEX on an element of TYPE

Tags: postgresql, types, indexing

I would like to create an index in an element of specific type.

Can you help me ? Thanks

```sql
CREATE TYPE taddress AS (
 street1 varchar,
 street2 varchar,
 zipcode varchar,
 city varchar
);

CREATE TABLE person (
    id serial primary key,
    firstname varchar not null,
    lastname varchar not null,
    address taddress);

CREATE INDEX idx_street1 ON person ((address).street2); -- <- Doesn't work !!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_street1 ON person (((address).street2));
```

And include a full error message if this doesn't works for you.